# MYSQL get between two dates

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get all the fields between two dates:

My query

```
SELECT * FROM `klj_agenda` WHERE date BETWEEN '1-05-2014' AND '30-05-2014'
```

This is my table

[image]

And this query doesn't give any output. Can somebody help me fix this problem?.

Comment: do you data in the specified date range

Comment: MySQL dates are in the form YYYY-MM-DD, i.e. '2014-05-01'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date is stored as 2014-05-01  so YYYY/MM/DD

```
SELECT * FROM `klj_agenda` WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-30-05'
```

Comment: its not wrong, it stil is stored as yyyy-mm-dd the only thing you added is the reason why it is stored like that. Thanks though =)